# Better query for joins

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

Ok so I have three tables like so

### Students

```
Name        StudendId
----------------------
John            1
Jane            2
Bob             3
Betty           4
```

### Class

```
StudentId   TeacherId
----------------------
1            1
2            2
3            1
4            2
1            3
4            3
```

### Teacher

```
Name          TeacherId
------------------------
Jim               1
Joan              2
Jill              3
```

Ok so I want to find the teacher who is teaching both john and bob.

So far my query is,

```
 select distinct Teachers.Name from Teachers, 
   ((select Teachers.Name from Class, Students 
     where Students.StudendId = Class.StudentId and Students.Name = 'John') as tbl1
    join
   (select Class.TeacherId from Class, Students 
     where Students.StudendId = Class.StudentId and Students.Name = 'Bob') as tbl2
   on tbl1.TeacherId = tbl2.TeacherId) where Teachers.TeacherId = tbl1.TeacherId;
```

So I wondering if this is the optimal way of constructing a query? I worry about this approach is that it doesn't seem to scale well as could be asking the common teacher of 25 students.

Thanks,
Vinh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.name
    FROM TEACHERS t
    JOIN CLASS c ON c.teacherid = t.teacherid
    JOIN STUDENTS s ON s.studentid = c.studentid
                   AND s.name IN ('John', 'Bob')
GROUP BY t.name
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.name) = 2
```

The `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.name)` must equal the number of names specified in the IN clause, because IN means the names could be John or Bob, in addition to teachers to have both students.  The `DISTINCT` insulates from the possibility of duplicate names (2x John, etc), which would be a false positive.

Comment: So if you're doing this programmatically for any number of students, you pass a list of student names into the query, and the `HAVING` clause = the number of elements in the list. Right?

Comment: Thanks, I knew there had to be a simpler way to do that query than my retarded way.  Btw OMG Ponies do have an account on gizmodo?

Comment: Yeah, aren't you their lead Pony Correspondent?

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems overly complex, just join the tables and filter on the results you want. Avoid unnecessary inline select statements. In this case I think group by may be more performant than distinct but prob not much in it. As long as the data is correctly indexed there shouldn't be scaling issues which such a simple query.

```
Select t.Name
From Teacher t
        inner join Class c on c.TeacherId = t.TeacherId
        inner join Students s1 on s1.StudentId=c.StudentId
        inner join Students s2 on s2.StudentId=c.StudentId 
Where s1.Name = 'Bob'
      and s2.Name = 'John'
Group By t.Name
```